# how to add type to custom field in opencart?

Tags: types, field, opencart, registration

I want to add code-id to registration form in **opencart 2.0.3.1**, but in admin panel just can choose

> this type---> ( choose, choose File, Date) , my type of field is `"int"` and `"unique"` and `"its Length"`is 10 ?

How can I do this?

Comment: no one can help me?:(

Comment: I don't know what you are looking for exactly.

Comment: i added "melli-code" to registration form,i want to customers just put number and it should be unique

Comment: سلام، خسته نباشید، قصد دارید کد ملی رو به فرم ثبت نام اضافه کنید و تنظیمات اپن کارت این اجازه رو نمی ده؟

Comment: سلام؛ ممنون، من کد ملی رو اضافه کردم، میخوام یک شرط بذارم بگم هر شخص با کد ملی یکبار ثبت نام کنه و فقط هم عدد 10 رقمی وارد کنه

Comment: سلام، فیلدهایی که از پنل مدیریت اپن کارت ساخته میشن، قابلیت اعتبار سنجی رو ندارن. من سعی می کنم در اولین فرصت این رو به صورت یه ماژول بنویسم و اینجا قرار بدم.

Comment: سلام واقعا ممنونم لطف میکنید

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom fields in Opencart don't have validation ability, so if you need validation, you must add your desired fields manually.

I've created a `vqmod` script that adds a new field with the type and length validation (it must be numeric with exactly 10 digits), the script adds new column `code_melli` with an `UNIQE` index to prevent storing a duplicated entry.

As the question is about registration form, this script prepared in this form only, if you want to let your customer edit it from their account or echo it in admin panel, you must improve it.

I've tested this on Opencart 2.0.3.1 with the default theme:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<modification>
    <id>Code Melli</id>
    <version>2.0.3.1</version>
    <vqmver>2.6.0</vqmver>
    <author>darbaze.com</author>

    <file name="catalog/model/account/customer.php">
        <operation error="skip">
            <search position="after"><![CDATA[extends Model {]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[
                public function checkCodeMelli() {
                    $hasCodeMelli = false;
                    $result = $this->db->query( "DESCRIBE " . DB_PREFIX . "customer");
                    foreach ($result->rows as $row) {
                        if ($row['Field'] == 'code_melli') {
                            $hasCodeMelli = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (!$hasCodeMelli) {
                        $sql = "ALTER TABLE `" . DB_PREFIX . "customer` ADD `code_melli` INT(10) NULL  AFTER `lastname`,  ADD   UNIQUE  (`code_melli`) ;";

                        $this->db->query( $sql );
                    }
                }

                public function getTotalCustomersByCodeMelli($code_melli) {
                    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "customer WHERE code_melli = '" . (int)$code_melli . "'");

                    return $query->row['total'];
                }
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
        <operation error="skip">
            <search position="iafter"><![CDATA[email = '" . $this->db->escape($data['email']) . "',]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[code_melli = '" . $this->db->escape($data['code_melli']) . "',]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>

    <file name="catalog/controller/account/register.php">
        <operation error="skip">
            <search position="after"><![CDATA[$this->load->model('account/customer');]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[
                $this->model_account_customer->checkCodeMelli();
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
        <operation error="skip">
            <search position="before"><![CDATA[if (isset($this->error['email'])) {]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[
                if (isset($this->error['code_melli'])) {
                    $data['error_code_melli'] = $this->error['code_melli'];
                } else {
                    $data['error_code_melli'] = '';
                }
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
        <operation error="skip">
            <search position="before"><![CDATA[if (isset($this->request->post['email'])) {]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[
                if (isset($this->request->post['code_melli'])) {
                    $data['code_melli'] = $this->request->post['code_melli'];
                } else {
                    $data['code_melli'] = '';
                }
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
        <operation error="skip">
            <search position="after"><![CDATA[function validate() {]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[
                if (!is_numeric($this->request->post['code_melli']) || (utf8_strlen(trim($this->request->post['code_melli'])) != 10)) {
                    $this->error['code_melli'] = 'کد ملی به درستی وارد نشده است';
                }
                if ($this->model_account_customer->getTotalCustomersByCodeMelli($this->request->post['code_melli'])) {
                    $this->error['warning'] = 'این کد ملی قبلا ثبت شده است';
                }
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>

    <file name="catalog/view/theme/*/template/account/register.tpl">
        <operation error="skip">
            <search position="before" index="1" offset="1"><![CDATA[<?php echo $entry_email; ?>]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[
              <div class="form-group required">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-code_melli">کد ملی</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <input type="code_melli" name="code_melli" value="<?php echo $code_melli; ?>" placeholder="کد ملی" id="input-code_melli" class="form-control" />
                  <?php if ($error_code_melli) { ?>
                  <div class="text-danger"><?php echo $error_code_melli; ?></div>
                  <?php } ?>
                </div>
              </div>
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>

</modification>
```